# how to direct a href to section using coordinate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to direct the page to specific coordinate when a href is clicked. Here is my attempt so far:

```js
$("#link").click(fuction(){
   $("body").position("top", "1000":"left","0") 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="" id="link">click here</a>
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question but can't you just use fragment identifiers? i.e.: `http://example.com/somepage.php#gohere`?

Comment: Did you find a method that worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery then you can use:

```
$("body").scrollTop(1000);
$("body").scrollLeft(0);
```

If you want to learn more, you can read [this](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/) and [this](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

Answer (score 0):

do like below for jquery

```
$("body").css({top: 1000, left: 0})
```

and small modification on HTML side too

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link">click here</a>
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```